# SetInterval, как сделать чтобы смещение каждые 800мс были на разное расстояние, рассчитанное случайным образом

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
let Car = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.spead = 40;

  this.draw();
};

Car.prototype.draw = function() {
  let carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

  this.carElement = $(carHtml);

  this.carElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });

  $('body').append(this.carElement);
};


Car.prototype.moveRight = function(distance) {
  this.x += distance;

  this.carElement.css({
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });

};



let tesla = new Car(20, 20);
let nissan = new Car(300, 70);


let t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 0 + 1));
setInterval(tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t), 800);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Math.floor( Math.random() * (200 - 0 + 1) ) -имеется в виду диапазон px от 0 до 200 из формулы Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сейчас вычисляете смещение лишь однажды, и потом запускаете `setInterval` с ним:

```
let t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 0 + 1));
setInterval(tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t), 800);
```

Очевидно, нужно вычислять каждый раз:

```
setInterval(() => {
    let t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 0 + 1));
    tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t)()
}, 800);
```

Правда, непонятно, чего вы хотели сказать выражением `Math.random() * (200 - 0 + 1)` вместо `Math.random() * 199`. Возможно, вы имели в виду что-нибудь типа `Math.random() * 200 + 1`.

Итог:

```js
'use strict';
let Car = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.spead = 40;

  this.draw();
};

Car.prototype.draw = function() {
  let carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

  this.carElement = $(carHtml);

  this.carElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });

  $('body').append(this.carElement);
};


Car.prototype.moveRight = function(distance) {
  this.x += distance;

  this.carElement.css({
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });

};



let tesla = new Car(20, 20);
let nissan = new Car(300, 70);


setInterval(() => {
    let t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 0 + 1));
    tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t)()
}, 800);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t)() - почему должны быть () в конце? что это значит

Comment: @user368267 потому что `tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t)` – это функция, а чтобы её вызвать, надо скобочки поставить. Можно это переписать так: `let moveRight = tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t); moveRight();`. `setInterval` сам по себе вызывает функцию, которую ему передают, поэтому в выражении `setInterval(tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t), 800)` вторая пара скобок не нужна

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Вынести `t` в анонимную функцию

```
setInterval(function() {
  let t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200-0+1));
  tesla.moveRight(t);
}, 800);
```

Comment: всё-таки `tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t)()`, иначе перемещение не будет выполнено)

Comment: @YakovL я бы даже сказал, что `bind` тут вообще не к месту

Comment: это может быть, я даже не стал вникать)

Comment: @YakovL почему должны быть () в конце? что это значит

Comment: @user368267 потому что `tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t)` – это функция, а чтобы её вызвать, надо скобочки поставить. Можно это переписать так: `let moveRight = tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t); moveRight();`. `setInterval` сам по себе вызывает функцию, которую ему передают, поэтому в выражении `setInterval(tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla, t), 800)` вторая пара скобок не нужна

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov  без bind не перемещает

Comment: @user368267 все отлично перемещает. При вызове `tesla.moveRight(t);`